# Lost my <div id=header> switching from HTML 5 to XHTML 1 Transitional

Tags: css, html, xhtml

So I'm a little stumped.  I needed to transition a few pages of a client's site to XHTML 1 Transitional to support a third party API from a company called Chamber Master.  They manage membership, job openings, deals, and other data for Chambers of Commerce.

My template was ok when I first made the transition, but the data wouldn't load.  Then when it would, it broke my template, ignoring CSS and script.

The integration team told me to use absolute paths to css and java files and to remove the  tag I had around my CSS file declarations.  Sure enough this worked... Almost.

While the CSS was loading and almost everything worked, now my header simply disappeared.

The rendered HTML which should read something like:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
         <nav>
    ...
         </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper>
    ...
```

Now looks like:

```
    <body>
    <div id="main-wrapper>
    ...
```

The file on the server still includes the omitted portion, but the rendered page leaves it off.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if we had some more information. How exactly are you transitioning (transforming?) the html?

Comment: `<nav>` is not a valid XHTML element, as far as I know, so it might be stripping that out.

Comment: Try running your html through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  Maybe there's something else you are missing that is causing this issue.

Comment: If there's a tool you're using for the conversion, it is probably a bit overzealous, dumping the entire `nav` element because it doesn't exist, and then dumping the enclosing `div` because it is now empty.

Answer (score 0):

`<nav>` element is HTML5, not supported by XHTML 1.0 Transitional

http://www.techonthenet.com/html/elements/nav_tag.php

Comment: This doesn't really explain what's going on/why it's being removed along with the parent `div` element.

Comment: I thought as much, but I'm not even getting my header picture or nav bg.